# Grouping a parent record with its child associations

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Given a table `Location`, where each row has many records in table `Events`, for example:

`Location` has columns: `id, city, state`

`Event` has columns: `id, name, date, location_id`

I want to perform a query that results in a structure like this (json array shown here):

```
[
    {
        location: {
            id: 1,
            city: 'San Francisco'
            state: 'California'
        },
        events: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name, 'Fest 1',
                date, 'March 1, 2022'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name, 'Fest 2',
                date, 'March 2, 2022'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        location: {
            id: 2,
            city: 'Seattle'
            state: 'Washington'
        },
        events: [
            {
                id: 3,
                name, 'Fest 3',
                date, 'March 3, 2022'
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                name, 'Fest 4',
                date, 'March 4, 2022'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm struggling to achieve this. I've tried various subqueries, and `GROUP BY` approaches but not getting what I need.

Comment: Please show the query have you tried and show how it misses the mark.

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_agg()` to create the array and `to_jsonb()` to convert the rows to json:

```
select
    to_jsonb(location) as location,
    json_agg(to_jsonb(event)) as events
from location
left join event on event.location_id = location.id
group by 1
```